# Laravel 5.1 Response Routing Location new line detected

Tags: php, laravel-5, cakephp

I try to redirect to an external app from laravel 5.1 using responses inside a controller:

```
$response = Response::make();
$value = trim("http://someapp.com/laraveltocake");
$response->header('Location:', $value);
return redirect($response);
```

I have no success as the error message was:

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Is there a better way to redirect from a Laravel route to an external app

In my case it is an legacy cakephp app module which still was not migrated to Laravel which is the goal of this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this:

```
return redirect("http://someapp.com/laraveltocake");
```

should be enough.

Comment: tahnk´s did not knew about it i amnew to laravel. great!!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!